# Store PDO Values in PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm stuck in a really silly problem, i want to store the value fetched by PDO query into variable. any solutions?

```
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT status FROM user_tbl WHERE user_id= :user_id");
$st->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$st->execute();
```

Comment: you say it is "fetched" but nowhere fetch can be seen in the code. Are you sure you posted the whole code?

Comment: i didn't posted the whole code, but i got the answer! thank you!

Comment: It's very bad for you not posting the whole code. It can make you unable to post questions in the future

Comment: sorry but i'll take care next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to return it..

```
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE user_id= :user_id");
$st->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$st->execute();

$return = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$return $return;
```

Then when calling your class in say index.php..

```
$var = new ClassName();
$callUser = $var->PublicFunctionTitle($user_id);
```

Then you can run things like `<?php echo $callUser->status;?>`

Comment: thnk you!! it workss!!

Answer (score -2):

You need to fetch the result of your select statement. Below is an example of how you should do it:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$status = $result[0]['status'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great!! it worked for me!! thanx alot!!

Comment: @shyamm this is the most ugly solution that will result in errors

Comment: @YourCommonSense but it works fine!!

Comment: @shyamm Just because 'it works' doesn't mean its the best route to go..

Comment: @Option  will you advice better solution then!!

Comment: @shyamm the difference between an ugly code and a proper code is that the proper code works **always** while ugly code will fail you when you don't expect it.

Comment: @shyamm, I've passed my answer as the way I'd personally approach such a thing.